# Functions with expressions don't work

Tags: javascript, html

I tested it in chrome and that time it worked, but now not anymore. Can you please tell me why is that? Any suggestions will be appreciated. I've also tested it in explorer, it's the same.
Here is the code:

```
function checkName() {
    var alphaExp = /^[a-zA-Z\-]+$/;
    var nume = document.getElementById('nume');
    var pren = document.getElementById('pren');

    if (nume.value.match(alphaExp) && pren.value.match(alphaExp) && nume.value.length >= 2 pren.value.length >= 2) {
        return true;
    } else {
        alert("Numele si prenumele trebuie sa contina doar litere si sa aiba mai mult de 2 caractere ! ");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is "the job"? How is it not done any more? Can you please reduce the code to include only the relevant pieces?

Comment: I reduced the code Bergi. That function has to check if I type the Name  according to that expression.

Comment: You're missing a `&&`. Also, what values did you put in that had unexpected results?

Comment: thank you very much Bergi. I can't believe I was so blind I couldn't see that mistake.